# How to dynamically import python module A in module B which uses module B

Tags: python, python-import

I'm currently developing the service which should dynamically import python code files (modules) and call function in each of these modules `AttributeError`. The problem, if I understood the error correctly, lies in the fact that I'm importing the module `Launcher` (module which initiated importing of the module `SomeModuleToImport`) in the module `SomeModuleToImport`.

How can I resolve it?
Also I will need to reimport module each time I need it because the code in `SomeModuleToImport` can be changed during runtime.

***Python version 3.6.1.***

**File structure:**

```
|
- Launcher.py
- SomeModuleToImport.py
```

**Launcher.py**

```
import importlib

script = importlib.import_module("SomeModuleToImport")
script.handle()

def writeMsg(txt):
  print(txt)
```

**SomeModuleToImport.py**

```
import Launcher

def handle(user, req):
  Launcher.writeMsg("Hello!")
```

**Error:**

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lexmint/Dropbox/Archive/Development/Breeze/Launcher.py", line 3, in <module>
    script = importlib.import_module("unban")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/lexmint/Dropbox/Archive/Development/Breeze/unban.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Launcher
  File "/Users/lexmint/Dropbox/Archive/Development/Breeze/Launcher.py", line 4, in <module>
    script.handle()
AttributeError: module 'SomeModuleToImport' has no attribute 'handle'
```

Comment: Reorganize your code so you don't have circular imports.  That's really the only way to fix it.  One way to achieve this is to think of your modules arranged in "layers", and modules should only import from layers below themselves.

Comment: Agree; you could declare `write_msg()` and other stuff in a separate module, leaving only the `handle()` call in `Launcher` module.